# Make a column a view

Tags: oracle

To be brief, I won't explain *why* I want to do this, just what I want to do.

I have two users (which I use as schemas) A and B. Both have a table USERS. Both USERS tables have a columns ID. Every A.USERS.ID is found in B.USERS.ID and every B.USERS.ID is found in A.USERS.ID (I put constraints on that). The only other shared columns between A.USERS and B.USERS is NAME and AGE.

EDIT: To make this clearer... The problem I have is that the values of NAME and AGE are not the same between schemas A and B. For example, user ID 723 in A has A.NAME='John Vincent'. In B, the B.NAME='JJ Vincent'. I want NAME and AGE to be the same at all times. So, I figure that I need to store it in one place and make it visible in two places.

When I let someone query B.USERS, I want B.USERS.NAME and B.USERS.AGE to actually be A.USERS.NAME and A.USERS.AGE. This is the query that I could use if I had permission to query both A and B:

```
select B.ID, A.NAME, A.AGE from B.USERS join A.USERS on B.USERS.ID=A.USERS.ID
```

However, I don't want to grant access to A to everyone. I only want to grant access to B (similarly, some people only have access to A and those people are the only ones I want to update the values of NAME and AGE).

I know I can't make just 2 columns be a view. Is there some other trick to make NAME and AGE be a view of A, but have permissions of B? I hope that I've explained enough to make sense. Just trying to avoid writing a dissertation.

Comment: It's possible I don't see the complication as you've explained it, but I don't see why you can't create a view from the query you supplied, and then grant access to the view alone?

Comment: If I make a view, can a user with access to B update all the columns in B that are not NAME and AGE from A? The goal isn't to make *all* of B read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant update, insert, delete on B and A to whomever should be able to get to either or.  If you want limited view based on your query, you can grant access solely to a view without granting access to the tables.

If you need column specific update access to B, then you *can* do "column level security" in oracle.

Something like "grant update (column_name) on table_name to user_name", and you'll have granted access to update only "column_name" in that table.

Comment: Thank you, but the issue is not really permissions. The issue that I have cases where, for ID 61124, I have A.USERS.AGE=28 and B.USERS.AGE=35.  I want those to be the same. I don't really care if A or B updates it. I want it to be the same. If that requires that B cannot update it, that is acceptable.